# FlutterFlow Pass Text as Parameter

Tags: flutterflow

I have a function that takes in a text input and spits out some other text.

Now i want to use the output of the function as a parameter to send to the next page, but there's no clear way on how to do it?

Please help!

I tried creating a component and then component local state but that broke my app

Comment: Is the function you are calling inside a component? If not, you should be able to use a local page state variable and update that value with the output of your function. Then just pass that variable in your parameter. If you provide more details on your page's setup, I can give you a better answer.